# How to use Mockito.doAnswer() with a void method with no parameters?

Tags: java, android, testing, mockito

```
@Test
public void successfulHandshake(){
    HandshakeImpl1Server handShake = new HandshakeImpl1Server();
    handShake.setHttpStatus((short) 101);

    authUnderTest.authenticate(callback);

    doAnswer(invocation -> {
        websocket.onOpen(handShake);
        return null;
    }).when(websocket).open();
    
    verify(websocket,times(1)).send(any(String.class));
}
```

doAnswer is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You need to stub your methods before, not after call to method under test.

Move doAnswer before call to authUnderTest.authenticate